# Merge list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am trying to merge 300 dataframes (these are polygons) into a single dataframe. I know how to do it two by two using `rbind`. Given the high number of dataframes I am looking for a way to merge them all together. Every dataframe has the same structure. One example:

> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields geometry type:
> POLYGON dimension:      XY bbox:           xmin: 18.62278 ymin:
> 2.720688 xmax: 18.68717 ymax: 2.773334 epsg (SRID):    4326 proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs   id
> source year                       geometry 1  2 HUELS POLYGON ((18.66028 2.773334...

```
# Load Data - EXCEL
shp_list<-(read_excel(".repository.xlsx",sheet="repos",skip=0))

# Loop to load shapefiles
for (s in 1:length(shp_list$shapefile)){

varName<-print(paste(shp_list$shapefile[s]))

  assign(varName,st_read(print(paste("./",gsub("trmc_","",shp_list$original_map[s]),"/",sep ="")),paste(shp_list$shapefile[s])))
}
```

Comment: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rcs mentioned you may use `bind_rows` which receives a `list` object of `data.frames` and binds them all together:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

file_list = list.files("shapefile_folder", pattern = "\\.shp", full.names = T)

geodf_list = lapply(file_list,  function(x) read_sf(x))

geodf = bind_rows(geodf_list)
```

besides that, when using `for` loops you should preallocate the vector with `vector(mode = list, length = list_length)` to avoid copying all the object at every iteration; or use `lapply`

Comment: If you don't want to pull `dplyr` in then `do.call(rbind, lapply(.....))` works just as well and is only using base R functions.